# Replace word in a list

Tags: python

I want to show on screen all the users that live in **Madrid** in the following format:

The user 'NAME', lives in 'CITY' has an age of 'AGE' years old and its debt is: 'DEBT' EUR.

As you can see the **different ways in which Madrid is saved**, I want to find a way to print these users, since a few write in capital letters and others do not, they all live in Madrid.

```
students = [
    ('Marcos', 23, 'Madrid', 850, '2388711341'),
    ('Elena', 35, 'MaDrid', 360, '0387700342'),
    ('Carmen', 21, 'Getafe', 50, '0014871388'),
    ('Carlos', 41, 'MAdrid', 580, '00887118456'),
    ('Maria', 28, 'Madrixx', 150, '587')
]
```

for item in students:
    student, age, town, debt, id = item

**The desired result:**

```
The user Marcos lives in Madrid, has an age of 23 years old and its debt is: 850 EUR.

The user Elena lives in Madrid, has an age of 35 years and its debt is: 360 EUR.

The user Carlos lives in Madrid, has an age of 41 years old and its debt is: 580 EUR.

The user Maria lives in Madrid, has an age of 28 years old and its debt is: 150 EUR.
```

Comment: Check out [str.title()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=title#str.title)

Answer (score 1):

To filter your output you can f.e. use a simple `if` condition on a all-lowercase `'madrid'`:

```
students = [
    ('Marcos', 23, 'Madrid', 850, '2388711341'),
    ('Elena', 35, 'MaDrid', 360, '0387700342'),
    ('Carmen', 21, 'Getafe', 50, '0014871388'),
    ('Carlos', 41, 'MAdrid', 580, '00887118456'),
    ('Maria', 28, 'Madrixx', 150, '587')
]


for item in students:
    # decompose the item into its parts - this also fixes your NameError
    student, age, town, debt, something = item

    # use the decomposed variables instead of item[.]
    # make town all lowercase and compare - only print if matches
    if town.lower() == "madrid":
        print(f'The user {student} lives in {town.title()}, has an age of '
              f'{age} and its debt is: {debt} EUR.')
```

Output:

```
# if you simply print town
The user Marcos lives in Madrid, has an age of 23 and its debt is: 850 EUR.
The user Elena lives in MaDrid, has an age of 35 and its debt is: 360 EUR.
The user Carlos lives in MAdrid, has an age of 41 and its debt is: 580 EUR.

# with town.title()
The user Marcos lives in Madrid, has an age of 23 and its debt is: 850 EUR.
The user Elena lives in Madrid, has an age of 35 and its debt is: 360 EUR.
The user Carlos lives in Madrid, has an age of 41 and its debt is: 580 EUR.
```

---

@marmeladze pointed out I missed Maria, who seems to be incapable of using her correct town-name - you can mitigate her inabilities by using:

```
if "madrid".startswith(town.lower()[:4]):
```

instead of

```
if town.lower() == "madrid":
```

to get an output of:

```
The user Marcos lives in Madrid, has an age of 23 and its debt is: 850 EUR.
The user Elena lives in Madrid, has an age of 35 and its debt is: 360 EUR.
The user Carlos lives in Madrid, has an age of 41 and its debt is: 580 EUR.
The user Maria lives in Madrixx, has an age of 28 and its debt is: 150 EUR.
```

I just hope you never get anybody from `'Madravingpeopletown'` into your list - they would show up as well...

Comment: your code will not classify Maria as a Madridista -))

Comment: @marmeladze Why should it? She does not live in `MaDrId` but in `Madrixx` - which is a totally other town ... you would have to use someting like `if town.lower()[:4] == "madr":`  or some other heuristic to get her - or teach her how to spell her town correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it very much ... Thank you all, I resolved the doubt. :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner as a software developer, i bet you've faced such situations hundreds of times. we need to handle out such user typos in proper way -))

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to identify what you want, but if you are trying to print alumni data living in Madrid, try below.

```
students = [
    ('Marcos', 23, 'Madrid', 850, '2388711341'), 
    ('Elena', 35, 'MaDrid', 360, '0387700342'),
    ('Carmen', 21, 'Getafe', 50, '0014871388'), 
    ('Carlos', 41, 'MAdrid', 580, '00887118456'),
    ('Maria', 28, 'Madrixx', 150, '587')
]



for student_detail in students:
    if student_detail[2].lower().startswith('madri'):
        print(f"The user {student_detail[0]}, lives in Madrid. S/He is {student_detail[1]} years old and has {student_detail[3]} as debt")
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome!

You will need to normalize all those names somehow. Given your sample data something like [capitalize()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.capitalize) method should work.

```py
[...]
for student in students:
    normalized_city = item[2]
    print(f'The user {student[0]} lives in {student[2].capitalize()}, has an age of '
          f'{student[1]} and its debt is: {student[3]} EUR.')
```

I would encourage you to do the normalization "before" storing the data so no matter how the users write their city you will always save it normalized.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it very much ... Thank you all, I resolved the doubt. :)

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
students = [
    ('Marcos', 23, 'Madrid', 850, '2388711341'),
    ('Elena', 35, 'MaDrid', 360, '0387700342'),
    ('Carmen', 21, 'Getafe', 50, '0014871388'),
    ('Carlos', 41, 'MAdrid', 580, '00887118456'),
    ('Maria', 28, 'Madrixx', 150, '587')
]
for student in [s for s in students if s[2].lower() == 'madrid']:
    print('The user {} lives in {}, has an age of {} years old and its debt is: {} EUR.'.format(student[0],
                                                                                            student[2].title(),
                                                                                            student[1], student[3]))

#
# A cleaner solution (using named tuple)
#

import collections

Student = collections.namedtuple('Student', 'name age city debt id')

students = [
    Student('Marcos', 23, 'Madrid', 850, '2388711341'),
    Student('Elena', 35, 'MaDrid', 360, '0387700342'),
    Student('Carmen', 21, 'Getafe', 50, '0014871388'),
    Student('Carlos', 41, 'MAdrid', 580, '00887118456'),
    Student('Maria', 28, 'Madrixx', 150, '587')
]
for student in [s for s in students if s.city.lower() == 'madrid']:
    print('The user {} lives in {}, has an age of {} years old and its debt is: {} EUR.'.format(student.name,
                                                                                            student.city.title(),
                                                                                            student.age,
                                                                                            student.debt))
```

Output:

```
The user Marcos lives in Madrid, has an age of 23 years old and its debt is: 850 EUR.
The user Elena lives in Madrid, has an age of 35 years old and its debt is: 360 EUR.
The user Carlos lives in Madrid, has an age of 41 years old and its debt is: 580 EUR.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it very much ... Thank you all, I resolved the doubt. :)

Comment: Eduardo. Consider use named tuple which make the code more readable. See my code.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

To convert all the different capitalizations of "madrid" and "getafe" (required met and city in it), use `string.lower()` and then match it against the lowercase of Madrid.

> str.lower()
>
> Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters [4] converted to lowercase.

I saw that no answers deal with the exception of "Madrixx", so this answer incorporates that. Feel free to choose a different one if you do not think this is necessary.

## So hence my code is:

```
students = [
('Marcos', 23, 'Madrid', 850, '2388711341'),
('Elena', 35, 'MaDrid', 360, '0387700342'),
('Carmen', 21, 'Getafe', 50, '0014871388'),
('Carlos', 41, 'MAdrid', 580, '00887118456'),
('Maria', 28, 'Madrixx', 150, '587'),
]

for student in students:
city = student[2].lower()
if city[:5] == "madri" or city == "getafe":
    print("The user %s lives in Madrid,  has an age of %d years old and its debt is: %d EUR." % (student[0], student[1], student[3]))
```

## Here is the output:

```
The user Marcos lives in Madrid,  has an age of 23 years old and its debt is: 850 EUR.
The user Elena lives in Madrid,  has an age of 35 years old and its debt is: 360 EUR.
The user Carmen lives in Madrid,  has an age of 21 years old and its debt is: 50 EUR.
The user Carlos lives in Madrid,  has an age of 41 years old and its debt is: 580 EUR.
The user Maria lives in Madrid,  has an age of 28 years old and its debt is: 150 EUR.
```

## An explanation:

We start by defining the dataset you mentioned. I copy pasted your code.

`for student in students` : this loops for as many items there are in the list. First, the variable `student` is **Marcos**, then it is **Elena** and so on.

`city = student[2].lower()` : this gets the *third* item in the list, the location, and converts it to lowercase.

`if city[:5] == "madri" or city == "getafe":` : this is to cope with the dataset. I check if the first five characters are "madri" (to include Maria living in "Madrixx") *OR* the city is "getafe", in madrid also.

`print("The user %s lives in Madrid,  has an age of %d years old and its debt is: %d EUR." % (student[0], student[1], student[3]))` : Here, we do some python string formatting magic. %s inserts a string, %d inserts an integer. We use %s, %d and %d for AREA, AGE and DEBT (in that order). Then, at the end of the string when we have closed the **"**, we put a `% (student[0], student[1], student[3])` which are the values to insert into the string.

Hope this is useful, and well done on translation!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it very much ... Thank you all, I resolved the doubt. :)

Answer (score -1):

for item in students:
    student, age, city, debt, id = item
    if city.startswith('M'):
        print(f'The user {student} lives in {city}, has an age of {age} and its debt is: {debt} EUR.')

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it very much ... Thank you all, I resolved the doubt. :)